# Delete set of lines from a file in AIX by passing variables

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to delete a set of lines from a file by passing variables.

Below is my file :

```
$ cat checking.txt
Starting1
DELETE /*+NESTED_TABLE_SET_REFS+*/ FROM tables1

Ending1

Starting2

update table

set col1=2
where val2=685

Ending2

Starting3

update table
set col1=1
where val1=44

Ending3
```

so in above files I need to delete lines from 1st line to 4th line.
I used below command and it was working fine.

```
sed '1,4d' checking.txt
```

Now I gave variable `a` a value, like `a=4`

```
echo $a
4
```

Now I tried the sed command like

```
sed "1,${a}d" checking.txt
```

`sed: 0602-404 Function 1,       4d cannot be parsed.`

Can someone please tell me how to pass variable here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Works fine for me with the variable.  What do you get from `echo "1,${a}d"` ?  And can you show us the line where you set `a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could attempt this problem is in the following way. Assuming you want to delete lines between `start` and `stop`, you could write

```
awk '(NR<start) || (stop<NR)' start=1 stop=4 file
```

The way you are proposing it to work also works,

```
start=1
stop=4
sed "${start},${stop}d" file
```

The reason why it failed in your case is because the variable `a` seems to have blanks in front of it. You notice this from the errormessage and the blanks space in front of the 4.